# RTSP streaming xml or text file

Tags: xml, streaming, rtsp

I am going to make a streaming xml/text file. Does anyone know whether it is doable?

As I know, RTSP normally is for media streaming, like mp3, mp4 and etc. Does it work for text file or xml file? If yes, can anyone suggest a streaming server for me to test it?

What I have searched like VideoLan and Live555 which are just for media. If no such a server, can I just use an Apache web server with PHP, for exmaple, with RTSP protocol specification to stream the xml file?

On the other hand, if I am going to stream a xml, the format should be StAX?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

yes - it is doable - we're doing this successful for a meta data stream of video analytics. We're using live555 and setting the marker bit each time we close the xml-file (approx. every second - directly starting a new one).

you have to make sure, that you're using a dynamic payload type (see [RFC2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) at section C.1.3 for this)

You can also read through the [Onvif specification for streaming](http://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf) (it is basically waht we're doing).

Comment: Interesting response! When I read the OPs question, I couldn't think of why anyone would want to stream XML :)

Comment: Hi jenseb, 
I'm a newbie about live555 and rtp format. Could you share your code for setup a meta data stream in rtsp server ? I also want to send video processing results along h264 data. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use RTSP to stream an XML file? IMO that doesn't make any sense. What does the XML contain?

As you stated it's for real-time streaming of multimedia. See the [RFC2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) if you need more info on RTSP. If you want to "stream" or to be more specific transfer/download an xml file, why don't you use protocols such as HTTP or FTP?

Comment: Actually, I just wanna stream a xml/text file. The file contain live message. So, I wanna keep stream the data. That's why I gonna do.

For HTTP, I just know that HTTP Live Streaming. However, it takes effort to build up another HTTP Live Streaming Server since I already have a RTSP streaming server for media. 

Do you have any suggestion to me? Thanks